# How to get Processing to work on Cloud9 using Ruby language?

Tags: ruby, ide, processing, cloud9

I am currently working on a personal project using the Ruby language in Cloud9 IDE. Recently, I came across an environment/programming language called Processing. My goals is to make Processing available for my use in Cloud9 IDE.

I am a complete novice and have no clue what I am doing. I followed directions from the following website: [Directions for setting up Processing](https://www.sitepoint.com/drawing-processing-ruby/)

I entered the following commands into Cloud9's terminal:

```
rvm install jruby
rvm use jruby
gem install ruby-processing
PROCESSING_ROOT: "/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java"
```

Entering in `PROCESSING_ROOT: "/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java"`
outputted message bash: PROCESSING_ROOT:: command not found

I wasn't too surprised by this, since the last entry probably needs information specific to my setup. Here are my questions:

1.) Are these directions correct for what I am trying to do? (get Processing to work in Cloud9 IDE). If they are not correct, can someone please point me to the correct directions, or give me directions?

2.) If these directions are correct, how can I successfully finish the last step? I tried running DrawRuby.rb, a simple program copied from the internet that supposedly made use of Processing. When I ran the code, the message "You need to set PROCESSING_ROOT in ~/.rpsrc" appeared. I am not sure if this piece of information is relevant or not, but I figured I would add it.

This is where I am at, and I am completely stuck. If someone could give me some help, I would be very grateful. Also, please make your explanation easy to understand. I am relatively new to the programming world, and may not necessarily understand terminology or how things should work.

Cheers!

*** Edit: I created a new workspace in Cloud9 IDE and tried Jed's suggestion. This is what happened:`echo 'PROCESSING_ROOT: "/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java"' > ~/.rpsrc
:~/workspace $ rp5 run Draw.rb
WARNING: you need to set PROCESSING_ROOT in ~/.rp5rc
NameError: uninitialized constant Processing::RP_CONFIG
Did you mean?  Config
               RbConfig
  const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3344
        spin_up at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/ruby-processing-2.7.1/lib/ruby-processing/runner.rb:188
            run at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/ruby-processing-2.7.1/lib/ruby-processing/runner.rb:105
       execute! at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/ruby-processing-2.7.1/lib/ruby-processing/runner.rb:67
        execute at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/ruby-processing-2.7.1/lib/ruby-processing/runner.rb:61
         <main> at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/ruby-processing-2.7.1/bin/rp5:10
           load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:979
         <eval> at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/bin/rp5:1
           eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1000
         <main> at /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:15`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a file to your home directory (`~/`) called `.rpsrc` and then add that environmental setting (`PROCESSING_ROOT`) to your file. The following should work from the command line in your cloud9 environment:

```
echo 'PROCESSING_ROOT: "/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java"' > ~/.rpsrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be a bit late for you but ruby-processing is now deprecated, and will only work with processing-2.2.1. For processing-3.3.7 use either [JRubyArt](https://github.com/ruby-processing/JRubyArt) or [propane](https://github.com/ruby-processing/propane) latter does not even require processing install.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using JRubyArt and propane but ran into errors-of course just my luck.